# Problema al compilar Android Studio : "Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy iniciándome en el mundillo de android así que me baje este proyecto `https://github.com/cubei/FlappyCow`

Me saltan estos errores de compilacion

```
Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1.
Searched in the following locations:
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle- 
3.2.1.pom
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle- 
3.2.1.jar
Required by:
project :BaseGameUtils
Open File
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**La solución es habilitar el repositorio Maven en tu proyecto.**

En la ventana donde se muestra el error al sincronizar tu proyecto con los archivos .gradle puedes habilitarlo, con un simple clic en el mensaje:

**`Enable embedded Maven repository and sync project`**

---

También lo puedes realizar de esta forma:

En `Android Studio` usando windows, ve al menu: `File` > `Settings` (en una Mac, `Android Studio` > `Preferences`) para abrir la ventana de configuración.

Dentro de esta ventana ve a `Build, Execution, Deployment` > `Gradle` > `Android Studio` , ahí habilita `Enable embedded Maven repository`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me servio, muchas gracias.